# Setup FTP Server for Remote Access Mac

Tags: macos, mac, networking, ftp, setup

I'm rather new to the field of servers and networking and have recently been trying to set up an FTP server on my Mac as an easy way to move files around. I'd like the server to be able to be accessed remotely. I've already enabled the FTP server function of Mac OS X (Mountatin Lion) through the Terminal. Therefore, the server is "running". However, since there is no interface between the machine its self and incoming traffic on the network router, the server is not visible outside of the network which it's connected to.

What must I do to enable access to the server (via a standard FTP client i.e. Cyberduck) outside of my network? I've taken a look at No-IP, and have set up an account, host, and the DUC software, but am still unsure as to how it actually works. I've also scored Google for relevant articles to no avail.

I'd be incredibly appreciative to anybody who could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the router at you house, open ports 20 and 21 and forward them to your server (the IP address of your server).  You'll need to look up port forwarding for your particular router.  Then find out what your public IP address is from home (go to whatismyip.com on a browser at home).  You'll be given an IP address.  Try FTPing to that IP address while NOT at home, the router should forward you to the FTP box you have set up.  Keep in mind that the IP address that your service provider gives you will change from time to time.

That is where No-IP comes in.  You will run a program on your Mac Server that reports your public IP address to No-IP (not the private one the server is using).  You will have a domain name assigned to your account (say xyz.com).  Whenever your IP address changes, the A record for xyz.com is updated with the new IP.  All you have to remember is the domain name, no matter how often the IP changes.

Comment: Thanks very much, @Everett. Worked great. I have another question posted below if you had any time to take a look at it. Thanks again!

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/459756/post-file-to-ftp-server-php